# Parsing a nested inference rule syntax

Tags: logic, parsing

Consider this expression.

[image]

$$\dfrac{\dfrac{\dfrac{\dfrac{}{\textsf{zero nat}}}{\textsf{succ(zero) nat}}}{\textsf{succ(succ(zero)) nat}}}{\textsf{succ(succ(succ(zero))) nat}}$$

I see several applications of an infix operator $\frac{\blacksquare}{\blacksquare}$. What are its syntactic properties: how tightly does it bind and how does it associate?

Does this read

> a is always true. If a is true then b is true. If "if a is true then b is true" then c is true. If "If 'if a is true then b is true' then c is true" is true then d is true.

so that the third bar from the top includes both bars above it,

or is it something else? How can I write this with parentheses in normal non-latex characters?

Comment: Not very clear... It seems a sort of "iterated" rule that says: *zero* is an object of type $\text {nat}$ (first line under the first horiz bar) and if *zero* is an object of type $\text {nat}$ also $\text {succ}(zero)$ is (first and second lines under the bar) and so on...

Comment: And yes, you reading is correct. In general, a rule $\dfrac { }{A}$ reads: ""statement" $A$ is true, and a rule $\dfrac {A}{B}$ says: if "statement" $A$ is true, also $B$ is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\dfrac{\dfrac{\dfrac{\dfrac{}{\textsf{zero nat}}}{\textsf{succ(zero) nat}}}{\textsf{succ(succ(zero)) nat}}}{\textsf{succ(succ(succ(zero))) nat}}$$

> I see several applications of an infix operator $\tfrac{~\blacksquare~}{\blacksquare}$. What are its syntactic properties: how tightly does it bind and how does it associate?

In a **Gentzen-style proof tree**, $\tfrac{~A~}{B}$ indicates that statement $B$ can be derived from statement $A$.   Further $\tfrac{~A~~B~}{C}$ indicates that statement $C$ can be derived from statements $A$ and $B$, an so on.   Also $\overline{~B~}$ indicates that $B$ is a theorem.

They associate transitively. $\tfrac{~\tfrac {A}{B}~}{~C~}$ indicates that $C$ can be derived from $B$, *and* $B$ can be derived from $A$; which means we have a proof that $C$ can be derived from $A$.

Thus your tree appears to read:

- zero is a natural, therefore the zero's successor is a natural, therefore zero's successor's successor is a natural, therefore zero's successor's successor's successor is a natural.
- Or: zero's successor's successor's successor is a natural, by the theorem that zero is a natural, and the (unstated) rule that the successor of any natural is a natural.

Comment: So that's different than what I thought: $\frac{\frac{A}{B}}{C}$ doesn't mean [C is derivable from [B is derivable from A]]. Right?